# How to Add Managed Meta Data Field to Available Hierarchy Fields

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata

I'm trying to set up metadata navigation for my library.

I am following the instructions at [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/set-up-metadata-navigation-for-a-list-or-library-HA102832523.aspx) on the Microsoft support site.

When I get to Step 4, I am not able to add "Managed Metadata Field". That is, it is not listed in the Available Hierarchy Fields box. 
It seems like it would need to be in order for the instructions to work. 
How can I get Managed Metadata Field to appear so I can add it to Selected Hierarchy Fields?

Comment: What you're basically saying is that you have a managed metadata field on the list, but it does not show as selectable when configuring managed navigation?

Comment: it does not show in the list of available hierarchy fields. It doesn't actually show up in the example on the Microsoft site, but shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You add managed meta data to a list as a column. Once the column is in place you will find it in the list of available hierarchy fields.

Answer (score 0):

Se debe incluir el tipo de datos a una de las columnas de la biblioteca, le saldrá la opción de metadatos administrados

[image]

Comment: Hi sebastiancalderonera. 
Please update your answer by providing translation in English.